# Updating a a dictionary entry with a collection stored in that dictionary

Tags: vba, dictionary, collections

It is probably easiest to explain this by showing some sample data first followed by my expected output.

I have a sheet that looks like this:

```
 Date       Agent    Case #   Minutes
 12/1/2016  Mary        6       15
 12/2/2016  Joe         5       34 'Not a typo, records are NOT sorted by date
 12/1/2016  Bob        20       10
 12/2/2016  Mary       17       11
 12/2/2016  Mary        7        9
 12/2/2016  Bob        17       24
 12/3/2016  Bob         1       47
 12/3/2016  Joe         9       20
 12/3/2016  Mary       12        6
 12/3/2016  Joe         9       10
 12/3/2016  Joe         6       22
```

I need the output to look like this:

```
Date        Agent Count    Case Count      Minutes
12/1/2016        2             2              25
12/2/2016        3             3              78
12/3/2016        3             4             105
```

Agent Count is the total number of unique agents and case count is the total number of unique cases for that day. Minutes is just a total of all the minutes for the day. Records cannot be sorted by date without major modifications to several existing procedures.

My approach to this was to create a dictionary keyed by date with the item being a collection of the 3 desired outputs. The collection would then contain a dictionary of names, a dictionary of cases, and a total of the minutes. This is the code I am using to achieve that:

```
Private Sub CreateSummarySheet()
    Dim dtDay As Date
    Dim rAllData As Long 'Row on all data
    Dim rSummary As Long 'Row on Summary
    Dim intMinutes As Long 'Minute total
    Dim wsSummary As Worksheet
    Dim wsAllData As Worksheet
    Dim dicCases As Object 'Dictionary of Cases
    Dim dicAgents As Object 'Dictionary of people
    Dim dicDates As Dictionary  ' Object 'Dictionary of dates
    Dim colDateData As Collection 
    Dim key As Variant

    Set wsAllData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("All Data")
    Set wsSummary = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary Page")
    Set dicDates = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    rAllData = 2

    'Loop through All Data until the end of the list
    While wsAllData.Cells(rAllData, 1).Value <> ""
        dtDay = wsAllData.Cells(rAllData, 2).Value

        'Is the date in our collection?
        If Not dicDates.Exists(dtDay) Then
            'Create a new collection for this day and add it to the dictionary
            Set colDateData = New Collection
            Set dicAgentss = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            Set dicCases = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            colDateData.Add 0, "Minutes"
            colDateData.Add dicAgents, "Names"
            colDateData.Add dicCases, "Cases"
            dicDates.Add dtDay, colDateData
        End If

        'Get this day's collection
        Set colDateData = dicDates.Item(dtDay)
        'Total the minutes
        intMinutes = colDateData.Item("Minutes") + wsAllData.Cells(rAllData, 3).Value
        colDateData.Remove "Minutes"
        colDateData.Add intMinutes, "Minutes"
        'Add unique names
        Set dicAgents = colDateData.Item("Names")
        If Not dicAgents.Exists(wsAllData.Cells(rAllData, 4).Value) Then
            dicAgents.Add _
                wsAllData.Cells(rAllData, 4).Value, wsAllData.Cells(rAllData, 4).Value
            colDateData.Remove "Names"
            colDateData.Add dicAgents, "Names"
        End If
        'Add unique Cases
        If Len(wsAllData.Cells(rAllData, 5).Value) = 15 And _
           IsNumeric(wsAllData.Cells(rAllData, 5).Value) Then
            'Looks like a Case so add it if it doesn't already exist
            Set dicCases = colDateData.Item("Cases")
            If Not dicCases.Exists(wsAllData.Cells(rAllData, 5).Value) Then
                dicCases.Add _
                    wsAllData.Cells(rAllData, 5).Value, wsAllData.Cells(rAllData, 5).Value
                colDateData.Remove "Cases"
                colDateData.Add dicCases, "Cases"
            End If
        End If

        'put the collection back in the dictionary
        dicDates.Item(dtDay) = colDateData
        rAllData = rAllData + 1
    Wend

    'Find the first blank row on the summary page
    rSummary = 2
    While wsSummary.Cells(rSummary, 1).Value <> ""
        rSummary = rSummary + 1
    Wend

    'Loop through the dictionary of dates to output the data
    For Each key In dicDates.Keys 'dtDate is the key
        Set colDateData = dicDates(key)
        Set dicAgents = colDateData.Item("Names")
        Set dicCases = colDateData.Item("Cases")
        With wsSummary
            .Cells(rSummary, 1).Value = key 'Date
            .Cells(rSummary, 2).Value = dicAgents.Count 'Total Unique Agents
            .Cells(rSummary, 3).Value = colDateData.Item("Minutes") 'Total Minutes
            .Cells(rSummary, 7).Value = dicCases.Count 'Total Unique Cases
        End With
        rSummary = rSummary + 1
    Next

    Set wsSummary = Nothing
    Set wsAllData = Nothing
    Set dicCases = Nothing
    Set dicAgents = Nothing
    Set dicDates = Nothing
    Set colDateData = Nothing
End Sub
```

The code errors out on this line:

```
        dicDates.Item(dtDay) = colDateData
```

The error is `Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment`. I'm guessing this is because I am attempting to assign a collection. How can I update the dictionary item with the updated collection object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your actual *question* is that you're working with an `Object`, but `Dictionary.Item()` is a `Variant` property.  When you try to assign a reference type (your `Collection`), it gets coerced into a `Variant` so the compiler doesn't catch the fact that you are using a non-reference assignment on a reference type.  Or more briefly put, you're missing the `Set` in front of the assignment:

```
Set dicDates.Item(dtDay) = colDateData
```

That said, you can actually delete that line entirely and it would function exactly the same way. The `Collection` that you store in `dicDates` isn't a copy that needs to be replaced - it's a reference to the same object.  Try this simple demo code if you need verification of that:

```
Sub Example()
    Dim foo As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim bar As Collection

    Set bar = New Collection    'Make a bar and add some items.
    bar.Add 1
    bar.Add 2
    foo.Add "key", bar          'Put it in the foo.

    Set bar = Nothing           '<--this destroys the *local* reference.

    foo.Item("key").Add 3       'Add a value directly via the return of .Item()

    Dim x As Variant
    For Each x In foo.Item("key")
        Debug.Print x           'Prints 1, 2, 3
    Next
End Sub
```

So... you can simplify your code by just wrapping that whole section in a `With` block and not pulling the reference into `colDateData` *at all*:

```
    'Get this day's collection
    With dicDates.Item(dtDay)
        'Total the minutes
        intMinutes = .Item("Minutes") + wsAllData.Cells(rAllData, 3).Value
        .Remove "Minutes"
        .Add intMinutes, "Minutes"
        'Add unique names
        Set dicAgents = .Item("Names")
        If Not dicAgents.Exists(wsAllData.Cells(rAllData, 4).Value) Then
            dicAgents.Add _
                wsAllData.Cells(rAllData, 4).Value, wsAllData.Cells(rAllData, 4).Value
            .Remove "Names"
            .Add dicAgents, "Names"
        End If
        'Add unique Cases
        If Len(wsAllData.Cells(rAllData, 5).Value) = 15 And _
           IsNumeric(wsAllData.Cells(rAllData, 5).Value) Then
            'Looks like a Case so add it if it doesn't already exist
            Set dicCases = .Item("Cases")
            If Not dicCases.Exists(wsAllData.Cells(rAllData, 5).Value) Then
                dicCases.Add _
                    wsAllData.Cells(rAllData, 5).Value, wsAllData.Cells(rAllData, 5).Value
                .Remove "Cases"
                .Add dicCases, "Cases"
            End If
        End If
    End With
```

Comment: Good catch. ByRef...not ByVal... *Doh!*